# Pygame - Looking for matches across 2 .txt files and user input

Tags: python, pygame

For my program I have 2 .txt files: one with correctly spelt words (wordsCorrect.txt) and the other with the same words, on the same line, but misspelled in some way. One of the misspelled words is picked randomly and displayed on screen. The user has to input the correct version of that word.

I tried to write some code for comparing the words in the .txt files, but can't work out how to check if user input matches the correct word which, in turn, matches the randomly picked word on screen. I'm sorry if this is badly explained, but any help would be great!

```
   while word_pick == True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            file1 = open("words.txt","r")
            file2 = open("wordsCorrect.txt","r")
            with file1 and file2:
                same = set(file1).intersection(file2)
```

Comment: you could keep all in one file - two words in one line. Now you can use `zip()` to create pairs of words - `pairs = list(zip(file1, file2))` But every word will have `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Don't open and read the files in the event loop, otherwise the files are read again and again every time an event is added to the queue, for example if you move the mouse or press a key.

I recommend storing the correct together with the misspelled words in one file (maybe a csv file), create a dictionary, open the file and add the misspelled words as the keys and the correct words as the values.

```
words = {}

with open('words.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        misspelled, correct = line.strip().split(',')  # Comma as word separator.
        words[misspelled] = correct
```

Then you can check if the user input is correct in this way:

```
current_word = 'bred'
user_input = 'bread'
if words[current_word] == user_input:
    print('Correct answer.')
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to zip the words in the two files together. This is a bit more error prone, since the files could, for example, have different line numbers.

```
with open('misspelled.txt') as f1, open('correct_words.txt') as f2:
    for misspelled, correct in zip(f1, f2):
        misspelled = misspelled.strip()
        correct = correct.strip()
        words[misspelled] = correct
```